# Update two different tables with a single HTTP request

Tags: rest, http, http-post, flask-restful, http-put

I want to write a http POST/PUT request that would need to update two fields in two different tables.

For example, I want to write a http request that would reset the marks obtained by a student in various exams like math, science, literature with each record being in different tables.

Is it a good practise to write a single post/put request that would do updates in different tables, although it's theoretically possible?

I'm writing the api in Flask.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good practise to write a single post/put request that would do updates in different tables, although it's theoretically possible?

That's a perfectly normal thing to do.

There are no constraints that require a one to one correspondence between your *resource* model and your *data* model.

Comment: Thank you. I have an additional question. Is it a good practice to run an update and delete under a single  post? I have one such requirement.